# How to call Post and Patch request for Microsoft Graph through dot net core code

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have already written the code for get all users method in dot net core that will get all users details from Microsoft Graph API. But i am unable to create/update/delete users through Microsoft graph API.

I am using

```
Uri Uri = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users");
var httpResult = httpClient.GetStringAsync(Uri).Result;
```

for get all users.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I strongly recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on getting started. Your question, as it stands today, is _really_ broad and doesn't include any examples of what you have already tried and what errors/blockers you encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I assume you want to create/delete/update a user using the MS Graph API.

We can refer to [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user) to create/delete/update the user.

Using the endpoint `POST /users` to create a user.

Using the endpoint `PATCH /users/{id | userPrincipalName}` to update a user.

Using the endpoint `DELETE /users/{id | userPrincipalName}` to delete a user.

First of all, we should have grant the permission for you application.

Comment: Yes, i have resolved the permission thing from Admin. Now, it's working fine.

Comment: Please provide me sample for patch request for console application.